# Исчезли элементы формы

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

C#, Visual Studio 2013. В одной из форм проекта неожиданно исчезли ВСЕ ее элементы: кнопки, диаграмма, textBox - ВСЕ. Остался лишь остов формы и FolderDialog. А, например, OpenFileDialog исчез как всё. В кодах появились соответствующие ошибки: "элемент отсутствует в данном контексте". Причем, я, как мне кажется, никаких специальных усилий для появления этого эффекта не предпринимал. Обратимо ли это явление, и почему оно могло возникнуть?

Comment: Вы бы хоть упомянули, это WinForms или WPF.

Comment: Судя по всему это WinForms и что-то где-то было удалено случайно

Comment: VladD Это WinForm. В интернете я нашел похожие и безответные недоумения.

Comment: Sublihim Что же нужно сделать, чтобы СЛУЧАЙНО удалить ВСЕ элементы, а форму и 1 компонент оставить?

Comment: Студия ругается на автоматически сгенерированный Form1.designer.cs или на файл, который Вы редактируете Form1.cs? Из вашего вопроса не ясно, что Вы хотите - спасти то, что сделали, или понять как это произошло.

Comment: Александр Муксимов. По-моему, изложено достаточно ясно: из формы пропали элементы, из designer.cs соответствующие записи, а  в Form1.cs появились соответствующие пропавшим компонентам ошибки. Хочу же я и того и другого, если это возможно

Comment: А не может быть такого, что вы создали приложение NET.Core, а нет NET.Framework?